# Is there an 'Instruments' style Sampler for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I want to see how long my JS spends in different methods so I can spot problems the same way as when I'm using Instruments to develop for iOS. Is this possible?

Comment: Webkit and Firefox (via Firebug) both have JavaScript profilers. That's not nearly as comprehensive as Instruments, but they do help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a code profiler. (I've never heard of it being called a 'sampler' before, but the description you gave is of a profiler)

On the desktop browsers, most of them have either a profiler built-in (IE8, Safari and Chrome have developer tools with a profiler) or as a commonly-used plug-in (Firebug for firefox).

These may help you.

However, your question implies that you're working on the iPhone/iPad. I don't know whether the version of Safari provided with these devices also includes the developer tools, but if not, I suggest using the desktop version of Safari - it will be close enough (especially for the purposes of testing Javascript) for you to be able to run some meaningful tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Javascript Profiling in Safari. Good.